# Tela de login igual a do Gmail

Tags: jquery, html, css, ux, usabilidade

Estive observando a tela de login do [Gmail](https://accounts.google.com/) tem o campo imput e um texto que fica como placeholder, mas quando o curso do mouse esta dendo do campo, este texto sobe e fica como label, alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Esse efeito faz parte do [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines).

Comment: Aqui há um exemplo no codepen, [Google Material Design Input Boxes](https://codepen.io/sevilayha/pen/IdGKH)

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu queria, agora eu desenrolo, valeu mesmo cara, muito obrigado